# Binding an ExpanderView do a viewModel?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, binding

I made some ExpanderViews and hardcoded everything. That worked and looked nice so I wanted to clean up and only write one ExpanderView in xaml and load everything else with a binding.
As far as I understood I need a ListBox around the whole thing to make it more dynamic?
This is my code so far:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ContactDe}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LocationName}"
                        IsNonExpandable="False">
                <toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationName}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" LineHeight="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderFontSize}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>

                <toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="test" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>

                <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Information}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The ContactViewModel-Class:

```
public class ContactDeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _locationName;
    public string LocationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _locationName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _locationName)
            {
                _locationName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LocationName");
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> _information;
    public List<string> Information
    {
        get
        {
            return _information;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _information)
            {
                _information = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Information");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I fill the ContactViewModel:

```
this.ContactDe.Add(new ContactDeViewModel()
            {
                LocationName = "Stuttgart",
                Information = new List<string>
                    {
                        "some text"
                    }
            }
            );
            this.ContactDe.Add(new ContactDeViewModel()
            {
                LocationName = "Böblingen",
                Information = new List<string>
                    {
                        "more text"
                    }
            }
            );
```

I made a SampleViewModel-File where I have:

```
<vm:MainViewModel.ContactDe>
    <vm:ContactDeViewModel LocationName="Location 1" />
    <vm:ContactDeViewModel LocationName="Location 2" />
</vm:MainViewModel.ContactDe>
```

In the preview-window it shows me 2 ExpanderViews with Location 1 and 2. But the same code doesn't work with the emulator or a real device. I don't really understand which Binding-Acces does what. It would already help me a lot if I could see a full example. I googled many tutorials but most only show 1 side, like a xaml without seing how the data is stored.

edit:
Now I edited the viewModel, so it's not a `List<string>` but a `List<Info>` with Info only containing `string Text`. So now I can say `ItemsSource="{Binding Text}"` which should be only 1 string at a time, right?

Comment: First problem I can see is that you are binding a list (Information) to a TextBlock.Text property which expects a string.

Comment: What i WANTED to do is bind every single string-value from the list to an own TextBlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comment to @dellywheel's answer, that you set `DataContext` this way :

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
```

that set DataContext for use in design-time only, hence it doesn't work in run-time. To set `DataContext` with similar approach for use in run-time, you can try this way :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ContactDe}">
    <ListBox.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </ListBox.DataContext>
    ........
    ........
</ListBox>
```

or this way to set `DataContext` in page level :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    ........
    ........
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Another suggestion, prefer `ObservableCollection` rather than `List` for use along with data binding. `ObservableCollection` automatically notify view to refresh whenever item added to or removed from collection.

Comment: I know that the SampleData is for design only. To bind my viewModel I used the first version, like you suggested: `<ListBox ItemsSource="[Binding ContactDe}">`. Somehow it just doesn't add anything in runtime. I reduced the viewModel to a minimum just to see that it does anything at all. I add 2 elements to it (see code in the main post) and even static data is not shown -> somehow it is not recognized.

Comment: Okay, error found -.-

In my xaml.cs I was missing this line:
`DataContext = App.ViewModel;`
dellywheel was totally right. I read 10 tutorials about binding of expanderviews and noone even mentioned this. Sure it's lower level stuff but it should be mentioned in a complete guide.

Sad that I can't answer it because of reputation level. Hope everybody sees it here!

Anyways, thanks guys!

Comment: The point in my answer isn't `ItemsSource="[Binding ContactDe}"` part, you know that already. The point is in `<ListBox.DataContext>...</ListBox.DataContext>` part. It is one way to set `DataContext` from XAML only, you can also set it from code as mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your bindings slightly

```
          <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding LocationName}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Information}"
                      IsNonExpandable="False">
                      <toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{StaticResource  honeFontFamilySemiBold}" LineHeight="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderFontSize}" />
                          </DataTemplate>
                      </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                          <toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate>
                                  <TextBlock Text="test" />
                               </DataTemplate>
                          </toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                          <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate>
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                              </DataTemplate>
                          </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                  </toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: In the Preview-Window shows me everything like it should be, but on emulator it doesn't work =/ Now I see I spelled it totally wrong in the original post, will edit that. And some other small changes..

Comment: check your DataContext for the page. What is ContactDe? a list of view models?

Comment: Atm it's `d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"` which contains stuff, you can see in the main post. It has the same structure like the data I'm creating at runtime. But somehow the preview likes the sampleData and the emulator/real device doesn't like the real data =/

Comment: d:DataContext is your design time data (will appear in visual studio and Blend). you need to set the real DataContext as well. in xaml DataContext={Binding YourViewModel} or code behind eg var vm = new MainViewModel(); this.DataContext = vm;

Comment: I don't have it set yet and testing didn't show any change. In other files I also don't use it oo"
I have a ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs and separate classes for the real viewModels. When I create a visual Item I set it's ItemSource to some viewModel. // Actually it doesn't bind properly even when I remove all but the locationNames. It's a very simple ViewModel now that only contains a LocationName String and nothing else. And I can't get the LocationName to be displayed on emulator/device.